# Spring MVC application runs everywhere but not on Google App Engine

Tags: spring, maven, google-app-engine, tomcat, jetty

I am trying to run a simple spring MVC application on GAE. 
The application gives 500 response and behave erratically for the redirect:/ responses return by the controller. 
This happens when I use `mvn appengine:deploy`

Funny thing is that the same application runs fine when

1. I preview the application using `mvn appengine:run`
2. Deploy the application on Tomcat 7
3. Use `mvn jetty:run`

Just the GAE is note ready to accept the same.

Also came to know that GAE used Jetty, but in the `appengine:run` I find that the same uses Tomcat.

Did anyone else face the same issue and could provide some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some issues with spring mvc on GAE as well.
It seem to be just fine on my local dev but once deployed it struggles when an instance is starting.

The errors shown in log are:

*The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)*

and

*org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/_ah/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' (Jdk14Logger.java:87)*

Right now I'm looking at the optimisation guide, maybe that helps.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization